# r pie chart with aes (..count..)/sum(..count..)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am interested in plotting a pie chart in r directly from the dataset and not using the table function.

This is what I have so far

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x= Species)) + 
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=factor(..x..)), stat= "count")+
          geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                  y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count", vjust = -.25) +
           coord_polar(theta = "y",start = pi / 3, clip = "off")
```

This is creating a polar chart like this below

[image]

What I am expecting is a plot like this

[image]

Any suggestions on where i am going wrong is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = 1, fill = Species)) + 
          geom_bar(position = position_stack(),
                   width = 1, color = "white",
                   size = 2) +
          geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..) / sum(..count..))),
                    stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
          coord_polar(theta = "y", start = pi / 3, clip = "off") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

And if you do the same thing on a random subset of iris, you get something like:

```r
ggplot( iris[sample(nrow(iris), 20),], aes(x = 1, fill = Species)) + 
          geom_bar(position = position_stack(),
                   width = 1, color = "white",
                   size = 2) +
          geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..) / sum(..count..))),
                    stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
          coord_polar(theta = "y", start = pi / 3, clip = "off") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: this works for the above toy dataset where there are 3 factors or categorical variable with 3 levels. If I apply this solution on a variable with 2 levels, the chart is misleading it shows both 40% and 60% with same size :(

Comment: I know you said you didn't want the additional steps, but in the situation described above, I believe using the solution I provided would help take care of that. Just in case you needed something rather than nothing. :)

Comment: @Science11 see my update. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data <- iris %>% 
        group_by(Species) %>% 
        summarise(n = n()) %>% 
        mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>% 
        mutate(ypos = cumsum(freq)- 0.5*freq)


data[,'freq']=round(data[,'freq'],2)

ggplot(data, aes(x= "", y=freq, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = percent(freq)), color = "white", size=6)+
  theme(legend.position="right")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am trying to avoid using the additional step of group_by, summarise, mutate etc..almost like what Allan proposed below